# Membership directory

Tags: profile, search, fields

I created a public list (directory) of members based on a relationship.  I was able to set-up a smart group with a profile and can see the list. But I want to customize the list by country, without creating a profile for each country. I read that you can append the url like this:  civicrm/profile&reset=1&force=1&gid=N&city=London

But it is not working.  What is the field name for countries?  Are country names stored as an integer or a text value such as France?  How do I get a list of fields and values for CiviCRM? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include the version of CiviCRM and (very important for this question) the CMS are you using. If you are using Drupal than there may be a different approach to take which may be better for your use case.

Comment: Rather than just say " I read"  you should state where you have read this information (preferably as a URL link). Someone reading this question may be able to help you if they can read the source of that advice.

Comment: We are using CiviCRM 4.4 with WordPress.  I read this information here:  http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Linking+Profiles

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this.  I was using the wrong field name.  The field name is "country-3" and I was using "country".